# Logparser not work in C#

Tags: c#, logparser

Error parsing query: The specified FROM-ENTITY "<1>" is invalid [The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.]

`<1>` is working when use in sql in Log Parser 2.2, the folder is exist.
Query is working if i following article - [LogParser DataProvider for ADO.NE](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18749/LogParser-DataProvider-for-ADO-NET)

```
        try
        {
            ILogRecord rowLP = null;
            ILogRecordset rsLP = null;

            LogQueryClass logQuery = new LogQueryClass();
            COMW3CInputContextClass comW3CInputContext = new COMW3CInputContextClass();

            string strSQL = @"SELECT " +
                         @"COUNT(*) AS [Requests], " +
                         @"DIV(DIV(SUM(cs-bytes), 1024), 1024) AS [MBytes received], " +
                         @"DIV(DIV(SUM(sc-bytes), 1024), 1024) AS [MBytes sent], " +
                         @"c-ip AS [IP Address], cs(User-Agent) AS [User agent], " +
                         @"MAX(date) AS [Last visit] " +
                         @"FROM <1> " +
                         @"GROUP BY [IP Address], [User agent] " +
                         @"ORDER BY [Requests] DESC";


            // run the query against W3C log
            rsLP = logQuery.Execute(strSQL, comW3CInputContext);
            rowLP = rsLP.getRecord();


        }
        catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException exc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Unexpected error: " + exc.Message);
        }
```

Comment: where it does not work, if works in logparser?

Answer (score 1):

The *<1>* "magic shortcut" only works with the **IISW3C** input format, which is the format that parses the W3C log files generated by IIS. In your code, you are using the **W3C** input format, which parses generic W3C-formatted logs and thus knows nothing about *<1>*.

Answer (score 0):

I found they is not working by follow this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13504/Simple-log-parsing-using-MS-Log-Parser-2-2-in-C-NE which is the line

```
COMW3CInputContextClass comW3CInputContext = new COMW3CInputContextClass();
rsLP = logQuery.Execute(strSQL, comW3CInputContext);
```

By make change as below than the query can be work

```
rsLP = logQuery.Execute(strSQL, null);
```